# Googlemap inside a custom dialog

Tags: android, google-maps, dialog, customdialog

Do anyone know if this is possible? I have a custom dialog box that contains a viewflipper. The first view is a linearlayout with some records. I wanted the second view to be the google maps with the same records but this time location based.

Since the mapview needs to extend mapactivity, and the activity that calls the dialog is already set up, I's starting to think it's not possible.

Comment: put android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" in activity tag in manifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely! When I add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to my map activity in the manifest, it comes up as a dialog. You can then control how the dialog appears by tweaking your map activity layout.

Comment: Awesome, i'm gonna test this out